# Editor tab disappeared in GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

The MATLAB GUI normally (for me) has 4 tabs in the upper left - Home, Plots, Apps and (I think) Editor. However the editor tab has disappeared and I cannot find documentation how to turn it back on. I tried the Layout->Default but that just arranges all the visible windows and doesn't re-enable to missing editor.

Does anyone know how to turn this back on?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `edit` in the command window.

Unfortunately you are right, there is no 'Editor' option in the Layout panel of Matlab's interface, and for obscure reasons it's not present in the default layout.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've checked Ratbert's answer as he got here before me but Mathworks tells me it disappears any time you're not actually editing any code. If that happens their answer was to just click on the New Script button. Doing that worked for me. Typing edit in the command window is (I think) doing the same thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that finds this thread at a later date I eventually debugged the root cause of this problem as a mouse that was failing. When attempting to close the open variables part of the GUI, when clicking the X in the upper left, the mouse was generating two clicks instead of one. The first closed the variables GUI, the second closed the editing GUI. Purchasing a new mouse resulted in no longer seeing the problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

in matlab command window, go on top right triagle and click, a drop down list will appear, select undock editor